# Filter 1 to n relation between subject and objects in RDF graph

Tags: python, rdf, linked-data, rdflib

I want somehow in python in **RDF graph** with **RDFlib**, to filter only the predicates that make `1:n` relation between subjects and objects.

Could anyone help me with this?

Comment: According to the documentation, rdflib allows you to query with SPARQL. This query might be nontrivial, I'm not sure, what you mean by "predicates that make 1:n relation between subject and object". Please, provide some input data and the output expected.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can not understand, what you are looking for… Could you paste into your question 10-12 triples of input data and 3-4 IRIs of output desired?

Comment: If I correctly understood your question, you can do so by performing a SPRQL request. RDFLib is now supporting SPARQL. Do you now what is SPARQL and how to use it ?

Comment: @StanislavKralin sorry to bother u again :) , is it possible to write a query in SPARQL to only filter the predicates that have 1:1 relation. i mean a subject with a certain predicate only lead to a single object and vice a versa ?

Comment: i wrote sth like this and i'm not sure whether it's correct or not                            
    """SELECT DISTINCT ?predicate
       WHERE {
           ?subject1 ?predicate ?object1 .
           ?subject2 ?predicate ?object2 .
           FILTER(?subject1 = ?subject2 && ?object1 = ?object2 )
           
       }""")

Comment: Your variant is correct. But I think, its performance might be lower on large datasets in RDFlib (I can't test).

Answer (score 1):

Let's consider the following example:

```
@prefix ex: <http:/example.com/ontology/>
@prefix owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>

ex:man   ex:hasWife    ex:woman
ex:man   ex:hasName    "Jean"
ex:man   ex:hasName    "Claude"
ex:man   ex:hasChild   ex:boy
ex:man   ex:hasChild   ex:girl
ex:woman ex:hasHusband ex:man
ex:boy   ex:hasParent  ex:woman
ex:girl  ex:hasParent  ex:woman
ex:man   ex:hasWife    ex:wife
ex:woman owl:sameAs    ex:wife
```

As well as I understand, the output should be:

```
ex:hasName
ex:hasWife
ex:hasChild
```

In order to get this output, one should execute the following SPARQL query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?predicate
WHERE {
   ?subject ?predicate ?object1 .
   ?subject ?predicate ?object2 .
   FILTER (?object1 != ?object2)
}
```

Using RDFLib, you can do it in this way:

```
import rdflib g = rdflib.Graph()
g.parse("your_file.xml")
qres = g.query(
    """SELECT DISTINCT ?predicate
       WHERE {
           ?subject ?predicate ?object1 .
           ?subject ?predicate ?object2 .
           FILTER (?object1 != ?object2)
       }""")

for row in qres:
    print("%s" % row)
```